# SLERP velocity and acceleration (3d Orientation interpolation)

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, manipulator, trajectory

Hey guys I am quite new to quaternions and I am a bit unsure as to how to use them. How are the velocities and accelerations trajectories determined using quaternions?

I have been using slerp to interpolate the orientations.

$$
\begin{align}
Slerp(Q_0, Q_1,t) = Q_0(Q_0^{-1}Q_1)^t
\end{align}
$$

Where $t$ is the interpolation parameter from $[0;1]$. I read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp#Quaternion_Slerp) that:

> *The derivative of $Slerp(q_0, q_1; t)$ with respect to *t*, assuming the ends are fixed, is $log(q_1 q_0^{−1})$ times the function value, where the quaternion natural logarithm in this case yields half the 3D angular velocity vector.*

This is further supported by a document I found on the topic of quaternion interpolation in animation [(Dam, E. B., Koch, M., & Lillholm, M., (1998))](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.6788&rep=rep1&type=pdf), where in equation: (6.12), they show the first and second derivative (using their notation):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}Slerp(p,q,h) &= \frac{d}{dt} p (p^* q)^h \\
&= p(p^* q)^h log(p^* q)\\
&= Slerp(p,q,h) log(p^*q)\\\\
\frac{d^2}{dh^2}Slerp(p,q,h) &= p(p^* q)^h log(p^*q)^2\\
&= Slerp(p,q,h) log(p^* q)^2
\end{align} 
$$

In other words, to get the second derivative of $Slerp$ you need to times the function value with $log(Q_1, Q_0^{-1})^2$.

**Is this legitimate?** And can I use these resulting quaternions for:

$$
\begin{align}
X_d = \begin{bmatrix}p_d\\ Q_d \end{bmatrix}, \quad \dot{X}_d = \begin{bmatrix}\dot{p}_d\\ \dot{Q}_d \end{bmatrix} \quad \ddot{X}_d = \begin{bmatrix}\ddot{p}_d\\ \ddot{Q}_d \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

where $p = [x,y,z]^\intercal$ and $Q = \{\eta, \epsilon \}$, and the dots $\dot{X}$ and $\ddot{X}$ are the respective velocities and accelerations.

Because I am not sure what to make of the results. Maybe because I don't really understand quaternions. For context here's an example:

Python:

```
import numpy as np
import quaternion
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 15]

t = np.linspace(0,1,100)
Q = np.zeros((4,100))
Qd = np.zeros((4,100))
Qdd = np.zeros((4,100))

rot0 = np.array([[ 1.0,  0.0,  0.0],
                 [ 0.0, -1.0,  0.0],
                 [ 0.0,  0.0, -1.0]])

rotf = np.array([[ 0.0, -1.0,  0.0],
                 [-1.0,  0.0,  0.0],
                 [ 0.0,  0.0, -1.0]])

q0 = quaternion.from_rotation_matrix(rot0)
qf = quaternion.from_rotation_matrix(rotf)

for i in range(100):
    slerp = q0 * (q0.inverse() * qf)**t[i]
    slerp_d = slerp * np.log(qf * q0.inverse())
    slerp_dd = slerp * np.log(qf * q0.inverse())**2

    Q[:,i] = quaternion.as_float_array(slerp)
    Qd[:,i] = quaternion.as_float_array(slerp_d)
    Qdd[:,i] = quaternion.as_float_array(slerp_dd)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1)
ax1.plot(Q.T)
ax1.set_title("Slerp")
ax1.legend(['w','i','j','k'])
ax2.plot(Qd.T)
ax2.set_title("Slerp_d")
ax2.legend(['w','i','j','k'])
ax3.plot(Qdd.T)
ax3.set_title("Slerp_dd")
ax3.legend(['w','i','j','k'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Three plots depicting SLERP and their derivatives for trajectories]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$, and the derivative of $\cos$ is $-sin$.

Given a [quaternion definition of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor):

> $q = \cos{a} + \mathbf{r}\sin{a}$
>
> $\mathbf{r}^2 = -1$

I would expect to see what is effectively a phase shift at every derivative level, and that's what I'm seeing in your curves. I noticed your magnitude seems to be growing, but that may be because you need to normalize at every step.

Comment: It was the magnitude that was throwing me off. Yup, thanks for pointing out that I forgot to normalize according to the timestep. I think this resolves it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a mistake in python code.
That is:

`slerp_d = slerp * np.log(qf * q0.inverse())`

I think the correct one is:

`slerp_d = slerp * np.log(q0.inverse()*qf)`